# Transfer HBITMAP pointer from C++ application to .NET C# application

Tags: c#, c++

I have a HIBITMAP object in my C++ application. I trying to accsess this object from C# application by pointer (for test): 
IntPtr ptr = IntPtr.Zero;

```
using (var proc = Process.GetProcessesByName("CamCapture")[0])
{
    bool res = ReadProcessMemory(proc.Handle, new IntPtr(0x0035f9ac), ptr, IntPtr.Size, out lpNumberOfBytesRead);
}
```

It return false.
When i trying to read a byte array - it works. 
byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];

```
using (var proc = Process.GetProcessesByName("CamCapture")[0])
{
   bool res = ReadProcessMemory(proc.Handle, new IntPtr(0x0035f9ac), buffer, 4096, out lpNumberOfBytesRead);
}
```

But I need a pointer to HBITMAP. What's wrong?

Comment: HBITMAP is not a pointer -- it's a handle. This means that it's opaque -- you can't get (directly) at what it refers to. Particularly not cross-process. What are you actually trying to do?

Comment: I have a generator BITMAP in C + + application. There is a C # application that uses unmanaged functions (dllimport). I use this function:
GetDIBits (m_hMemDC, m_hBitmap, 0, (uint) Math.Abs ​​(m_nHeight), _ptr, ref m_bmi, 0). ToString ();
I want to obtain a m_hbitmap from the C++ application. At present i save an image  as bitmap file and then open it in C# application. But i think it is not good.

Comment: The HBITMAP from the C++ application won't mean anything -- it's a handle, so it doesn't point to anything -- and it doesn't mean anything in any other process -- you need to call GetDIBits in the C++ application and read those bits out, or use some other IPC mechanism, such as writing the bits to a socket or pipe as they're captured.

Comment: Yes, passing IntPtr.Zero for the "lpBuffer" argument is never going to work.  Lots and lots of other reasons it won't work, including a HBITMAP not being usable in another process and the increasingly low odds that hardcoding the address can still work on modern Windows versions or that it would be valid in the first place.